# AWS Credential error

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, media

I am trying to connect to AWS from my php application(Laravel). My intention is to use the AWS Media convert Service. Please see the code I have used.

```
$client = new MediaConvertClient([
    'profile' => 'default',
    'version' => '2017-08-29',
    'region' => 'us-west-1',
    'credentials' => [
        'key' => $key,
        'secret' => $secret,
    ],
]);

$URI = $client->getEndpoint();
$endpoints= $client->describeEndpoints();
```

This is the error I am getting.

`Cannot read credentials from /.aws/credentials`

Does anyone have an idea about how to resolve this issues?

Comment: Check your files permission

Comment: @Andra why would they want to check their file permissions when they clearly are passing all the credentials in the constructor of the class, and expect it to accept them as such

Comment: It's trying to access the file `/.aws/credentials` at some point, which is not shown in the code here. I'm going to guess the path may be wrong, as it's probably looking for a hidden directory in the system root.

Answer (score 4):

Finally, I got the answer. Removing the below line helped me to read the credential from `$key` and `$secret` (which is defined in the configuration file)

```
'profile' => 'default',
```

Comment: Thank you for posting the answer to your question, it helped me

Comment: When i saw this answer, i prayed that I had this line in my code! Thank god I did lol, saved the day ty!